# Issues with Drag and Drop of a Button on Android

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I want to be able to move a button around when the user drags it. I am using the Drag and Drop API introduced in API level 11 and it kind of works. Here is the code:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);

            final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                    v.startDrag(null, new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);

                    return true;
                }
            });

            findViewById(R.id.test_main_layout).setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                            button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            break;

                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                            button.setY(event.getY() - button.getHeight() / 2.F);
                            button.setX(event.getX() - button.getWidth() / 2.F);
                            break;

                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                            button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                    }

                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
    }

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/test_main_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/edit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit"
            android:text="Some text"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

The behavior currently is that when the user hold the button, it disappears and its 'shadow' appears and is dragged around. Then, when dragging is done, the shadow is replaced with the real button.

There are two issues with the way it works:

1. It has a bad-looking flicker when the user stops dragging? It looks as though for a short moment the shadow is gone and the real button is not yet shown. Is it possible to somehow get rid of it?
2. The behavior changes when an EditText has focus. Just change the TextView to EditText in the XML to reproduce it. With this change, the original button doesn't disappear while the shadow is being dragged, both are visible! Why is that and how to fix this?

I am testing it on two devices, one with 5.0.1 and the other one with 5.1 and the behavior is consistent (both issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue #2 (the button not disappearing) is caused by this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=25073. In short, for some reason, mu onDrag() with ACTION_DRAG_STARTED is never called as the EditText (or actually TextView)#onDragEvent returns true when it has focus:

```
case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            return mEditor != null && mEditor.hasInsertionController();
```

mEditor is not null in this case. For my, I changed the logic to not rely on the start being called, moved the code elsewhere and it works fine.